# JFrog xray ancestor for docker

Tags: artifactory

I am currently deployed two A and B artifacts in artifactory and those are indexed in xray. B is the base image is in A. I was in xray ui looking at B, but then in ancestor tab I am not finding A as ancestor listed.

Please let me know anything I am missing.

**Edit:**

Basically my aim is to fetch the ancestors of certain artifacts to ascertain component relations, running some ui regression tests. It deals with currently types - npm, maven, pypi and docker. Any pointers towards any similar issues with these types are appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you see in the UI related to the way Xray index docker images, I'll explain.
when Docker image is been indexed in Xray it indexes the manifest.json (abstraction of the docker image) as the root parent and the layers as it's descendants.

Note: the ancestor/descendants view you see in the UI is relation based on checksum

If docker B has 2 layers once it becomes the base layer of docker A it will be shown as 1 layer in Docker A (with different checksum)

In the example, you provided above you have :

```
             Docker-A (manifest.json)                  Docker-B (manifest.json)
                    /          \                            /           \
                   /            \                          /             \
                 1/             2\                       1/              2\    
 Base Layer(B)+Another Layer(B) Another Layer(A)   Base Layer(B)  Another Layer(B)
```

Manifest of Docker-A is not the ancestor of manifest Docker-B, therefore, you will not see it in the UI.

If, for example, Docker-B will have only one layer and it the base layer of docker-A then the same layer with the same checksum will be shown in Docker-A

```
       Docker-A (manifest.json)                  Docker-B (manifest.json)
                /          \                                  |           
               /            \                                 |            
             1/             2\                               1|                     
      Base Layer(B)    Another Layer(A)                Base layer(B)
```

In this case, if you check the ancestor's tab of the Base Layer(B) you'll see both Docker-A and Docker-B

Comment: thank you for the reply, this is a great explanation. Just to get one of my issues resolved, is there a way we can derive this new checksum - (Base Layer(B)+Another Layer(B)) out of B's manifest.json, to figure out A's manifest.json?

Comment: No, it can't be derived from B's manifest.json. the new checksum of (Base Layer(B)+Another Layer(B)) calculation is done on this new layer once Docker-A is built

Comment: Thanks again. One more related query Chen. I was checking the other types and the ancestors, the NPM components does not return ancestor at all. Does similar logic to docker apply to NPM as well?

Comment: Npm has a slightly different logic. Please provide more info, is the NPM package is deployed by itself with NPM repo?  or it is part of a docker image.

Comment: I have both aspects, as a docker layer in docker repo, and some components packaged as npm artifacts in npm repo.

Comment: I am looking for checking ancestors for certain types. Have updated the original question. Please check.

Comment: in order to see ancestors, the packages should have a relation of an archive to archive . for example, if a zip file contains a Jar file (inside), then zip will be the ancestor of the jar file and so on. JFrog Xray supports the following archive types: Zip family  (jar, war, NuGet, and ear), tar (gz,xz, and another compression), 7Z, RPM, Debian, Binary (Golang)

Comment: Hi chen. Thank you very much. I am going to try this.

Comment: Hi Chen. If you can please, explain the working of NPM ancestor. I am not able to find it. Is there a way to package it?  I package it as part of docker as well as publish it as NPM in the artifactory.
For all types - If parent and child being in separate repo, did it affect the display of parent and child in UI?  

Also I tried to package pypi as gz than whl, and package this in another gz, it did not show up.

Please let me know what is incorrect here. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can package an NPM package inside a docker however it should be done when you build the docker file, add the docker package at that point. you can use the NPM client to resolve the NPM package dependencies via different remote repository, after the docker will be built from a dicker file you'll be able to see the relation of the docker image to the NPM packages